# Do I have to name package with small letter

Tags: java, package, nomenclature

do I have to use first small letter in a package name while creating my own package?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: You don't have to, but its a good idea to follow convention.

Answer (score 3):

It is standard [java code convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You should use **ALL** small letters in package naming.
[Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Answer (score 0):

preferred but not obligatory. As an example [org.omg.CORBA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/package-summary.html)